# Percentage of good products (normal distribution)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

**Task:**

The automatic machine stamps parts, the length of which is practically reliably contained in the range from $49.7$ to $50.3$ mm. A part is recognized as standard if the deviation of its length from the nominal, equal to $50$ mm, does not exceed $0.25$ mm. Find the percentage of defects in products manufactured by the machine.

**Solution:**

Let the $\xi$ - automatic machine stamps parts params, and $\delta = 0.25, \, \sigma = 0.3$. So,for finde percentage I should to use such formulas:
$$
\mathbf{P}(|\xi - a|< \delta) = 2\Phi\left( \frac{\delta}{\sigma} \right) .
$$

So
$$
\mathbf{P}(|\xi - a|< \delta) = 2\Phi\left( \frac{0.25}{0.3} \right) = 0.5934.
$$

But correct answer is $\approx 1.24\%$. I do not quite understand how such an answer was received in principle. I hesitate a little at this moment, do you have any ideas where I was wrong?

Comment: That's the two-tailed probability for being $2.5$ SDs from the mean, so now the question is within how many standard deviations is it "reliably contained"?

Comment: @J.G.

Why 2.5 $\sigma$?  I understand correctly that in this case the value will lie within $[49.375; 50.625]$

Comment: I divine that from solving $\Phi(z)=1-\frac12\times0.0124$. To be precise, it's $z=2.5006$, but then $1.24\%$ isn't exact anyway.

Comment: @J.G.

So I'm trying to understand why it happens this way, if we assume that the answer is not known, then how to get $\Phi(z), z= 2.5$. And $1.24 $ - answer in solution manual